Error message when reaching .../.auth/login/google?... : ClientId not found for 'google' provider
In Visual Studio: in a Developer Command Prompt: you start the Static Web App Emulator with the following command:
swa start http://localhost:5152 --api-location http://localhost:7238

When you see the message [swa] - Waiting for http://localhost:5152 to be ready then you start Start the application (with or without debugging).
In the browser: be sure the URL is http://localhost:4280/
You reach the page for signin with Google with the following URL
http://localhost:4280/.auth/login/google?post_login_redirect_uri=/useredit
Expected behavior:

Current abnormal behavior

So at this time, reaching http://localhost:4280/.auth/login/google?post_login_redirect_uri=/useredit gives the error message on the page 'ClientId not found for 'google' provider'
I noticed if I remove this "google" config from my staticwebapp.config.json it works again (as expected)
Just for testing: reaching http://localhost:4280/.auth/login/gooooooogle?post_login_redirect_uri=/useredit works. I mean I'm not getting the error message ClientId not found for 'google' provider anymore and I'm reaching the Azure Static Web App Emulator as expected.
Tried to clear the cache of the browser + the Local storage + tried with another browser as well. Without luck.
Additional info
It was working perfectly fine (for weeks) until today. AFAIK I didn't changed/updated anything on my machine. Same problem occurs on another computer. Same problem occurs with another project. But no problem when deployed on AZURE. This problem is only occurring locally with the Azure SWA Emulator.
Below my staticwebapp.config.json
  {
    "navigationFallback": {
      "rewrite": "/index.html"
    },
    "routes": [
      {
        "route": "/api/import_users",
        "allowedRoles": [ "admin" ]
      },
      {
        "route": "/api/export_users",
        "allowedRoles": [ "admin" ]
      },
      {
        "route": "/api/export_posts",
        "allowedRoles": [ "admin" ]
      },
      {
        "route": "/api/hello_protected",
        "allowedRoles": [ "authenticated" ]
      },
      {
        "route": "/api/hello_protected_admin",
        "allowedRoles": [ "admin" ]
      },
      {
        "route": "/api/hello_protected_superadmin",
        "allowedRoles": [ "authenticated" ]
      }
    ],
    "auth": {
      "rolesSource": "/api/roles",
      "identityProviders": {
        "google": {
          "registration": {
            "clientIdSettingName": "GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID",
            "clientSecretSettingName": "GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }


Have you tried setting client ID as an environment variable? @Bronzato

FYI downgraded SWA CLI version to 1.1.7 and it's back to functional
